# JQuery delete closest element from Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, firebase

So I append my chatbox with records from Firebase, but I would also like to delete those records. Now I am not a genious with JQuery and thus I would like to know what should be used. In the original example they use data-id's

```
//Delete when clicking element
jQuery('body').on('click', 'a#message', function() {
   var $rec = $(this).closest('[data-reactid]');
    var id = $rec.attr('data-reactid') || null;
    if( id ) {
       // Delete nested elements
       $rec.find('[data-reactid]').each(function() {
          ref.child($(this).attr('data-reactid')).remove(); 
       });

       // Delete record
       ref.child(id).remove();
    }
    return false;
});


ref.on('child_removed', function (snapshot) {
    $('ul.chat-messages').find('[data-reactid="'+snapshot.name()+'"]').remove();
});
```

This is the original example:
http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/QnUpb/

My output is a bit else than the example, it is build as follow:

```
<ul class="chat-messages" data-reactid=".1.1.1.1">
   <ul id="ulrecords">
     <li id="limessage">[some message here]</li>
     <li>[additional info for message</li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

Basically in the first 'li' i have a  to activate the JQuery and when i click that delete button in the 'li', I want to delete the "ulrecords"

Hope anyone can help me with this

Comment: Which one is the close button? is it inside `<ul id="ulrecords">`?

Comment: it is inside the first <li> element and is as follow: <a id="message href="#">X</a>

Comment: instead of id `ulrecords`, you must use css class `ulrecords`. Because Id must be unique in a page.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm doing that now. But what about the [data-reactid]'s?